# An issue with QMessageBox openeing multiple times if I switch back and forth between windows

Tags: qt

I've a strange issue with `QMessagebox`.

I've two MainWindows which I navigate back and forth

Window 1 = `StageOneMain` that has fucntion called `eventHandler`

Window 2 = `StageTwoPatients` that has fucntion called `eventHandlerTwo`

Both `eventHandler` and `eventHandlerTwo` are to handle some events in each of these windows and are same as follows (I've mentioned `eventHandler` below but `eventHandlerTwo` is same):

```
void StageOneMain::eventHandler(STIM_GUI_TOPIC_T topic, uint8_t index, uint8_t reg, uint32_t value)
{

    if (topic==TOPIC_STIMULATOR)
    {      
        switch(reg)
        {
           case STIM_REG_NUM_SMART_SENSORS:
           if(value==0){
               QMessageBox::critical(this, "Sensor Not Connected!", "Reconnect the sensor and press Ok to continue");  //--------> Issue asscociated with this 
               return;
           }
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

There is `QMessageBox` to inform if a device is being disconnected, defined as above.

Also from window 1,  `StageOneMain` there is a push button to open  window 2, `StageTwoPatients` as follows:

```
void StageOneMain::on_pushButton_patients_clicked()
{
     this->close();
     stagetwopatients = new StageTwoPatients(this);
     stagetwopatients -> show();
}
```

And , from window 2, window 1 is opened as follows:

```
void StageTwoPatients::on_pushButton_Home_clicked()
{
    this-> close();
    StageOneMain *newPatient = new StageOneMain(nullptr);
    newPatient-> show();
}
```

Now the issue here is,

If I go back and forth between these window multiple times (say 3) and when the device becomes disconnected, there are multiple `QMessageBox` are popping up. But Ideally there should be one `QMessageBox`.

I dont know if this is an issue with how I open those windows or `QMessageBox` itself.

Can anybody spot an issue here?

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created a new window 2 each time the button in window 1 is clicked (and vice versa). This is caused by the line

```
stagetwopatients = new StageTwoPatients(this);
```

So if you click that button twice in window 1, there will be 2 window 2, and when the event comes, 2 message boxes will be shown for 2 window 2.

You can stop that by moving the construction of the windows elsewhere. Maybe construction both windows in main window for example, and each window keeps a pointer to the other. For example:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"

#include <QDialog>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QVBoxLayout>

class SwitchingDialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    SwitchingDialog(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QDialog(parent)
    {
        auto button = new QPushButton{tr("Switch")};
        connect(button, &QPushButton::clicked, this, &SwitchingDialog::switchDialog);
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout{this};
        layout->addWidget(button);
    }

    void setDialogToSwitch(QDialog *dialog_to_switch)
    {
        dialog_to_switch_ = dialog_to_switch;
    }

private:
    void switchDialog()
    {
        this->close();
        if (dialog_to_switch_)
            dialog_to_switch_->show();
    }

    QDialog *dialog_to_switch_ = nullptr;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    SwitchingDialog *dialog_1 = new SwitchingDialog{this};
    dialog_1->setWindowFlag(Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint, false);
    dialog_1->resize(200, 100);
    dialog_1->setWindowTitle(tr("Dialog 1"));

    SwitchingDialog *dialog_2 = new SwitchingDialog{this};
    dialog_2->setWindowFlag(Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint, false);
    dialog_2->resize(200, 100);
    dialog_2->setWindowTitle(tr("Dialog 2"));

    dialog_1->setDialogToSwitch(dialog_2);
    dialog_2->setDialogToSwitch(dialog_1);

    dialog_1->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Perhaps can you show me an example , on your last point?